# Is there a way to use ER Diagram as Database Schema? If yes, how can I use it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-schema, erd

I made a ER Diagram in MySQL Workbench. I want to use that as my schema. Is there a way to use import/use it? Or do I have to create a Database Schema for that manually?

Comment: If I recall correctly there's a "Forward engineer" menu somewhere.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've composed a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Workbench's terminology goes like this:

- Reverse Engineer: generate a diagram from a live database
- Forward Engineer: generate an actual database from a diagram

[image: Database/ Forward Engineer]

There's also a *Synchronize Model with Database* wizard you'll probably need when you make further changes in either side.